# POSTing json data with grequests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grequests

I need to make async POST requests with grequests.

My post body (in json), is this:

```
[{'params': {'source': 'widget',
   'id': 'http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/ww/beta/y3.gif',
   'groupId': '@self',
   'nolog': 'true',
   'userId': '@viewer'},
  'method': 'pos.plusones.get',
  'id': 'p',
  'jsonrpc': '2.0',
  'apiVersion': 'v1',
  'key': 'p'}]
```

I need to change `[0]['params']['id']` key's value to different URLs for the many POSTs I'll make.

So I'm doing:

`myrequests = (grequests.post(POST_URL, data=fgp(a_url) for a_url in all_urls)`

The `fgp()` method in my generator comprehension is a method that changes the `[0]['params']['id']` to the `a_url` passed to it, in the POST body I'm sending.

And when I map the requests to responses:

`myresponses = grequests.map(myrequests)`

This is what I get, as many times as there are requests (obviously).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/src/gevent/gevent/greenlet.py", line 340, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/grequests.py", line 71, in send
    self.url, **merged_kwargs)
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 307, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 456, in prepare_body
    body = self._encode_params(data)
  File "/home/ashk/.virtualenvs/cosignp3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 89, in _encode_params
    for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
<Greenlet at 0x7f0f7cbf33d8: <bound method AsyncRequest.send of <grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x7f0f7c90d080>>(stream=False)> failed with ValueError
```

**EDIT: Problem solved** :-

I got to playing around, and put in the headers just like you would in the `requests` module.

I'm setting the headers kwarg argument to make encoding none, and content-type:

```
(grequests.post(POST_URL, data=fgp(a_url, j=True), headers={'Accept-Encoding':'none', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}) for a_url in urls)
```

And now I'm getting the output correctly:

```
In [64]: resps[0].json()
Out[64]: 
{'result': {'isSetByViewer': False,
  'kind': 'pos#plusones',
  'metadata': {'type': 'URL', 'globalCounts': {'count': 0.0 }},
  'id': 'http://example.com/dfg',
  'abtk': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
 'id': 'p'}
```

Note: Output edited a little bit to hide some data.

Comment: So where do you encode the data to JSON?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh yes. Thank you. That's the problem. But now my problem is, that I'm getting a response body of bytes like `07\x04\xc3`pO\x01\x00\x00'`. How can I set Content-Type header to 'application/json' to get a proper response?

Comment: Sounds like the server is giving you a bad response then; compressed but without the headers to tell you so. You can set the extra `Accept-Encoding` header on the session.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a close paren in that line of `grequests.post` that you've shown. However, assuming it's actually there at the end of the line:

```
myrequests = (grequests.post(POST_URL, data=fgp(a_url) for a_url in all_urls))
```

that means that you're generating only a single `post` call but with multiple values for `data`. I think what you mean instead is:

```
myrequests = (grequests.post(POST_URL, data=fgp(a_url)) for a_url in all_urls)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to send *JSON* data; have `requests` encode this for you (and set the correct content type), by using the `json` argument instead of `data`:

```
myrequests = (grequests.post(POST_URL, json=fgp(a_url)) for a_url in all_urls)
```

Comment: Nope. Getting this: `b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x8c1\x0e\xc3 \x14C\xafRy\xce\xc0\x90\x89\x1bt\xeb\x1eep\xcbW\x84\x04\xf9\xca\x87fA\xdc\xbdD\xd9;\xda\xcf\xcf\rb\xa6\x06\xdf\xf0\xd1 \xf0\xb3s\x13\xb2\x94\xc2m$<\xf7\x93)\x86\x87\xc9\xf1\x95R1!\xb0\x12~i\x08\x9a\x19\xf7\xb1\xd9\x92\xbe\x99\x062a\xd1\xab\x89\xb7\xf5\xa21K\x15\xc3\xbf\xcb\xbe\xf6\xfe\x03X\x97\xb8\xf1\x87\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: I checked to response' `requests.headers`, and I see this: `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'`. I didn't ask for it. Know how I can change it? I'm going to try a couple of things in the grequests.post method call.

Comment: @bad_keypoints: that looks like compressed data; is the server using `Accept*` headers that tell clients to send bodies compressed?

Comment: @bad_keypoints: or is this the *response* you are getting from the server? I'm a little confused where this data is coming from.

Comment: The binarized hex string is the data.

Comment: So is there a `Content-Encoding` header on the request?

Comment: @bad_keypoints: not that I can actually decompress those bytes with the standard options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76052/discussion-between-bad-keypoints-and-martijn-pieters).